# Django single checkbox questionaire

Tags: python, django, web

I want to do something like that:

```
 CHOICES=(
 (1,"1"),
 (2,"2"),
 (3,"3"),
 (4,"4"),
 (5,"5"),

 satisfaction= forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)
```

And only one answer should be picked... However I cant! I also tried forms.CharField and ChoiceField with the above way but didnt work... Is it possible to have x options  and only 1 can be picked through forms.MultipleChoiceField?

Comment: If you want only one thing to be picked at a time, why do you use `MultipleChoiceField`? What does `ChoiceField` sound to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want one item to be selectable, you should definitely be using a `ChoiceField` for this, and should use a `radio` input / widget (check boxes are not the right input type for this use case):

```
CHOICES=(
    (1,"1"),
    (2,"2"),
    (3,"3"),
    (4,"4"),
    (5,"5")
) 
satisfaction = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=CHOICES, 
    widget=forms.RadioSelect()
)
```